# How to copy a char* to a char in c++

Tags: c++, copy, char

I have been working on a question in c++ but im stuck in a part.
It is a long code but I will only post a small part of it where i am stuck now. Here it is;

```
char* x = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
char y = (char)malloc(sizeof(char));
y = *x;
```

The problem is when I do it, if X points to a char named "HELLO", when i print y it only prints 'H' letter.

I want to copy the whole word that char* has into a char variable. Also I dont know the sizes of the char's, because they are given by the user. So the length could be anything. I tried strcpy() but couldnt managed to solve the problem.

Any help appreciated.

**Thanks for all the comments. Now I decided to use std::string according to your comments. And I guess Im never gonna use malloc again. Now I have to go back to code and change everything according to string and check if everything works.

Comment: If this is C++, you should learn std::string long before trying out malloc().

Comment: If this is really C++, you probably shouldn't be using `malloc` and you probably should be using the `std::string` type.

Comment: Don't use `malloc` and `free` in C++ - look into `new` and `delete` for memory management.

Comment: Regarding edit: "No operator matches these operands" is commonly seen on MSVC++ when someone forgets to `#include <string>`. Also, you should not `new ifstream`, it's just `ifstream inFile("C:\\Temp\\AAA.txt");`

Comment: @Cubbi, I found that i had forgotten <string> and added it before any comments. But with your comment I tried ifstream inFile("C:\\Temp\\AAA.txt"); but it gives error. Whats wrong with new, if its completely wrong how can I write it like you stated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To paraphrase Inigo Montoya, I don't think this code means what you think it means.

`malloc(sizeof(char))`

This allocates a certain amount of memory.  How much memory is allocated is dictated by `malloc`'s parameter.  In this case you're passing `sizeof(char)` which is, by definition, one byte exactly.  Therefore, you are allocating one byte of memory.

If you insist on using `malloc` (more on this later) then what you should be doing is figuring out how long the string you want to store is, add one more byte for the NULL terminator, and then `malloc` that much.  In the case of the string `Hello, world.` which is 13 characters, the corresponding call would be:

`malloc(14)`

Next:

`char y = (char)malloc(sizeof(char));`

`malloc` returns a pointer to the memory it allocated for you.  `y` in this case isn't a pointer, it's just a `char`.  The two aren't the same.  It compiles and *appears* to work because you use the bludgeoning tool known as a C-style cast:  `(char)malloc(...)`.  This tells the compiler, "I know I'm pointing the gun at my foot.  Just do what I tell you and don't complain."  Which it dutifully does.  But you're doing the wrong thing for several reasons:

1. `malloc` returns a pointer but you're trying to cast it to a `char`
2. You only allocated 1 byte but you assumed you were allocating a whole string's worth of memory
3. `y` is just a `char` but you treat it as if it were a whole string.

So if you again insist on using `malloc`, you need to do something like this:

```
static const char* HELLO = "Hello, malloc.";

char* x = malloc(strlen(HELLO)+1);
strcpy(x, HELLO);
char* y = malloc(strlen(x)+1);
strcpy(y, x);
```

But, you shouldn't be using `malloc` at all in C++.  Instead, you should be using `std::string`:

```
std::string x = "Hello, string.";
std::string y = x;
```

This is better because:

1. `string`s manage thier own memory.  You don't leak memory like you did in your code.
2. `string` is type-safer.  You violated type safety when you cast the return from `malloc` to a `char`.  You can do it, but *its not a `char`*.  That's bad.  `string` won't let you shoot yourself like this without great effort.
3. It's less code.  The best code is the code you never write.

Comment: Wouldn't strlen() fail sometimes because you did not null-terminate your char string?

Comment: @0A0D:  Assuming that by "fail" you mean "do the wrong thingm," definitely.  Hence, all the strings in my code above are NULL-terminated.

Comment: One must not assume that it is null-terminated as a piece of advice due to code become insecure.

Comment: @0A0D:  A better rule of thumb is to know what are safe assumptions, and what are not.  If I assert that `"Hello, string."` is guaranteed to be NULL terminated, that is a safe assumption.

Comment: If you say so. PCI won't tell you that next time you have to encounter a security audit.

Answer (score 5):

IT shouldn't - it should crash, in fact it probably shouldn't even compile!

The line `char y = (char)malloc(sizeof(char));` doesn't make sense

malloc reserves some memory and then return a pointer to that memory - you can't assign a pointer to a non-pointer variable such as 'y'

Also in the 1st line you have asked malloc to reserve memory for a single char ,sizeof(char)=1, not the number of characters the user has entered.

Comment: Correct, although I'd add that it won't compile because `malloc` returns a `void *`, so casting that to a `char` will most certainly fail.

Comment: Agreed. What it is saying is "allocate a single character of memory" then cast said memory pointer into a char, lopping off all but the lower 8 (16?) bits of the address.

Comment: FWIW, the `malloc` function returns a pointer. The OP is assigning a pointer variable to a `char` variable.  However, the casting of the return value from `malloc` prevents the error reporting by the compiler.

Comment: While true, not terribly helpful.

Comment: @Thomas - surprised that any compiler would let you cast a void* to a char without mentioning it!

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a whole word into a `char` variable because the `char` type only holds one character. Since there is no `string` type in standard C, you need to use an array of characters to represent a string.

Additionally, the `malloc` function only ever returns a pointer, because the memory you are trying to allocate resides somewhere on the heap. There is no way(*) to dynamically grow or shrink the stack to contain a variable-length value.

(*) There is no way in standard C, though there is some room for it using decidedly nonstandard functions that aren't portable.

Answer (score 1):

**Prefer `std::string`.**

Because C style strings use pointers, you cannot copy them using assignment (`operator=`).

You will have to use the `strxxx` family of functions, such as `strcpy` for copying.  **Remember to allocate memory for the receiver before copying.**

Answer (score 0):

Everything about this code is wrong. The first line allocates space for one character, and stores the address in x. The fact that it's holding more than one character without crashing is pure luck. The second line is even worse, because it allocates space for one character, then turns the address into a single character.

It should look more like this:
char *x=(char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*sizeOfYourString);
char *y=(char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*sizeOfYourOtherString);

strcpy(x, y);